# Organize a backbone.js collection?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

How does one create a collection (in backbone.js) that is organized by an id. For example I would think it's quite common that collections need to be organized by date, category, keyword, type the list goes on. In my case I am trying to find an elegant way to organize players to team.

I don't think I need a plugin for this, my goal is just to organize the players to be grouped inside a div while using one clean json file so I can have a nice organized list. Again ideally it would be nice to use one json file for this, and structure the HTML similar to how the json itself is structured in terms of nesting, in my example `league` being the parent of everything, then `team` being the parent of the `players`.

I have gone through many backbone tutorials multiple times, and understand the flow and syntax pretty comfortably, but all tutorials work with one collection outputting a simple list in no specific order.

Basically I want to be able to create a clean json array like below. Then turn it into nice organized HTML.

```
{
  "league":
       [{
        "team":"Lakers",
        "players": [
                {
                    "name": "Kobe"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Steve"
                }
        ]
        },
        {
        "team":"Heat",
        "players": [
                {
                    "name": "LeBron"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mario"
                }
        ]
        }]

}
```

So this json structure is valid but it's not one I have used it's nested a little bit more, so accessing the models requires a little different technique, I am hoping to learn if this kind of array is ideal? Also if so how would I group say `Kobe`, `Steve` inside a div with perhaps the class name `Lakers` whilst obviously separating it from `LeBron` and `Mario` keeping those two inside a div with again perhaps a class of `Heat`.

Another example I could use would be like a actors to movies collection, again is the json format ideal (seems like it to me) here I obviously group actors to their respected movie? I would greatly appreciate some tips on building a clean view or views with a template or templates for outputting this nice and tidy.

```
{
  "movies":
       [{
        "title":"Prisoners",
        "actors": [
                {
                    "name": "Hugh Jackman"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Jake Gyllenhaal"
                }
        ]
        },
        {
        "title":"Elysium",
        "actors": [
                {
                    "name": "Matt Damon"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Jodie Foster"
                }
        ]
        }]

}
```

Again just working with this json data and backbone.js how do I create a maintainable view for this array?

**Final Note:** I was able to successfully group players to teams using two json files, and assigning a player and id that matched the team id, then looped the team collection with the player collection inside using `where` to organize it (I am trying to rethink this better). To me this is not taking advantage of backbone, it can get confusing and just seems wrong to me. So again I hope to improve my knowledge here and get better. I would immensely appreciate clear concise information, I really struggle to wrap my head around this topic :)

**THANKS!!**

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm confused why you want to organise your JSON like this when backbone collections have a very easy to use `comparator()` method that organises/sorts all models in the collection.

Comment: Well I myself am not 100% certain on an approach, things like the `comparator()` are new and need to be learned. I learn best by asking and appreciate you bringing that option into scope, could you please elaborate do I need to change the structure of the json file what do I need to do :)

Comment: Obviously taking a look at that on the docs, but an explanation would do me wonders.

Comment: Applicable links, anything would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by building a working model of your data. Your JSON suggests a hierarchy : a collection of teams that each have a collection of players. Here's a possible implementation :

```
var Player = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Players = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Player
});
var Team = Backbone.Model.extend({
    constructor: function(data, opts) {
        // I like my subcollections as attributes of the model
        // and not on the settable properties
        this.players = new Players();

        Backbone.Model.call(this, data, _.extend(opts, {parse: true}));
    },
    parse: function(data) {
        // Players are handled in a subcollection
        if (_.isArray(data.players))
            this.players.reset(data.players);

        // They are removed from the model properties
        return _.omit(data, 'players');
    }
});
var Teams = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Team,
    parse: function(resp) {
        return resp.league;
    }
});
```

Now you can create your root collection. Note that you could also `fetch` it instead of instantiating it with the data.

```
// teams list
var teams = new Teams(data, {parse: true});

// for example, to get all players in all teams
var allplayers = _.flatten(teams.map(function(team) {
    return team.players.models;
}));
console.log(_.invoke(allplayers, 'get', 'name'));
```

And a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/8VpFs/

Once you have your structure in place, you can worry about rendering it. Let's imagine you have this (Underscore) template

```
<ul>
  <% _(teams).each(function(team) { %>
      <li><strong><%= team.team %></strong>
        <ul>
          <% _(team.players).each(function(player) { %>
              <li><%= player.name %></li>
          <% }); %>
        </ul>
    </li>
  <% }); %>
</ul>
```

You can alter your `Team` model to output a serialized representation of you model:

```
var Team = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // ... as before

    toJSON: function() {
        var json = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.call(this);
        json.players = this.players.toJSON();
        return json;
    }
});
```

and render your template

```
var tpl = _.template($('#tpl').html());
var html = tpl({
    teams: teams.toJSON()
})
$('body').append(html);
```

This usually would go into a view.

http://jsfiddle.net/8VpFs/1/

With a `fetch`

```
var teams = new Teams();
teams.fetch().then(function() {
    var tpl = _.template($('#tpl').html());
    var html = tpl({
        teams: teams.toJSON()
    });
    $('body').append(html);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8VpFs/2/

Comment: Hey thanks, I need to soak up as much info as possible, let me get this into my head brb. This looks good, you definitely took that json data and made it work, nice. Curious to know what you think about approaching it this way, @David Barker mentioned keeping the json in a backbone friendly structure, should I rethink the approach or is this efficient, I can see I may have trouble editing models and interacting with the RESTful api?

Comment: Basically I am asking are you just working with my json array, or do you actually think this hierarchy designed array is sufficient? The result looks good, and I am excited about this answer, but I hope it wont cause issues later on will it?

Comment: This is definitely a more comprehensive approach and to be fair Michael, there is nothing wrong with your JSON structure as a hierarchical list, it certainly avoids duplication. As @nikoshr has demonstrated it does add an element of complexity when building it into models / collections.

Comment: Yeah I can see that, I am really soaking up as much as I can, if I could vote both you guys I would. It does look the comparator is a little less work. But it's new and I can wrap my head around @nikoshr's code even though there is a lot more, just because I need to play around with the comparator a little, ill be marking an answer soon, again you guys are great.

Comment: I believe in normalized databases and structured data, so the hierarchical approach is more to my tastes. Moreover, a flat collection might be a bit more difficult to handle if you want to display something besides a list of players. But if what @DavidBarker proposed suits your needs, go for it

Comment: Looks like this suits my needs better (really appreciate the fiddles), the fact that there are so many ways to approach patterns and such in backbone.js confuses me, but this works well and isn't too much. If I fetched the data how do I pass in an argument into the `constructor` and `parse` methods, sorry but I am slow.

Comment: The `Teams` collection was missing a `parse` method to handle the `league` root attribute. You shouldn't have to change anything (besides a `parse: true` option) between an instanciation and a `fetch`. The Fiddles have more params to get them working

Answer (score 3):

Keep your JSON in a Backbone friendly structure, this will mean your models are easily organised once they are placed into the collection.

**JSON example**

```
[
    { league : 1, team : 'lakers', player : 'kobe' }
    { league : 1, team : 'lakers', player : 'steve' }
    // And so on
]
```

Consider that most backbone collections are built via a RESTful JSON api this would be easy to  fetch directly into a collection and then sorted. The `comparator()` function on the collection is run each time a model is added to the collection, or when you ask for it to run.

**Backbone collection example**

```
var Players = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize : function() {
        // Grab the JSON from the API
        // this.fetching is now a deferred object
        this.fetching = this.fetch();
    }

    // Comparator example one, as a string
    comparator : 'team',

    // Comparator example two, as a function
    comparator : function(model) {
        return model.get('team');
    }

});
```

The comparator as a function approach is obviously better suited to more complex sort algorithms, otherwise the comparator as a string approach would be better. Bear in mind that the function approach, though a string can be returned (such as above), `-1` or `1` would be better return values to indicate it's sort position.

**Comparator example with model comparison**

```
comparator : function(modelA, modelB) {
     var teamA = modelA.get('team'),
         playerA = modelA.get('player'),
         teamB = modelB.get('team'),
         playerB = modelB.get('player');

     if (teamA < teamB) { // string comparison
         return 1;
     } else if (playerA < playerB} {
         return 1;
     } else {
         return -1;
     }
}
```

Now whenever a model is added to the collection it is sorted into it's correct location, if using the last example, by team and then by player name.

**Simple view example using the collection**

```
var ViewExample = Backbone.View.extend({

    el : "#example-container",

    render : function() {

        var self = this;

        // Use the deffered object to make sure models are
        // all available in the collection before we render
        this.collection.fetching.done(function() {

            self.collection.each(function(model) {

                self.$el.append('<p>' + model.get('player') + '</p>');

            });

        });

        return this;
    }
});

// Create the view and pass in the collection
// that will immediately fetch it's models
var view = new ViewExample({
    collection : new Players()
});
```

**Code here is untested**

Comment: Good write up, I appreciate it, now I am going to attempt to implement it into my project. So using the comparator method I could output the html like this? `<div class="teamName"><div class="playerName1"></div><div class="playerName2"></div></div>`

Comment: Yeah you could output it like that just by iterating over your collection.

Comment: Cool, so that conditional that returns `-1` or `1` handles the comparison? Could I use that inside a template? If so what do I pass, I am sorry I almost get it, but its not 100% transparent I need to play around with this, but do you think you could provide a very very basic example (of using comparator to render basic html), ill for sure mark this answer as solved.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. a return value of 1 means it is 'above' the compared model and the inverse is true when -1 is returned. I've added a simple view example using the collection.

Comment: Thanks appreciate the effort it's set in stone now, can't believe I got another answer he does a good job working with my array, but you make a point about RESTful and keeping it friendly, this approach is new to me but seems much less work in terms of the amount of code needed. I need to read all this one more time brb. Again thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Wow okay starting to see how cool the comparator is, I just need to nest it inside a div now. I think you show how to render the players and I see the comparator nicely organizes the players by teams, but I don't think the example shows how to wrap each player into a div? Could you possibly explain that?